# Run New Thread on Timer Android

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I've been working on an android app which regularly checks a mysql database using JSON and everything works fine with my code.

Im having trouble running this as a timer as it only runs once and then stops.
The only code i managed to get working runs the http request on the UI thread which freezes up.
Any help would be most appreciated.
Thank in advance,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    checkUpdate.start();
    ...
}

private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // my code here to get web request to return json string
        } 

        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                    mHandler.post(showUpdate);
    }
    ...
}


private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            // my code here handles json string as i need it
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"New Job Received...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showja();
        }
    }
}


private void showja(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, JobAward.class);  
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();   
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't indented correctly... makes it really hard for us to read.

Comment: Your post is missing a lot of information (i.e. what is the `mHandler` variable, what class is the `onCreate` method in, where is the code that has the timer, etc.)

Comment: why don't you use asynctask for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Raghunandan suggested, the standard way to perform work in the background on Android, and then modify the UI when that work is done, is using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

First define a new subclass of `AsyncTask`:

```
private class JsonRequestTask extends AsyncTask<HttpUriRequest, Void, String> {
     protected String doInBackground(HttpUriRequest... requests) {
         // this code assumes you only make one request at a time, but
         //   you can easily extend the code to make multiple requests per
         //   doInBackground() invocation:
         HttpUriRequest request = requests[0];

         // my code here to get web request to return json string

         String response = httpclient.execute(request, responseHandler);
         return response;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String jsonResponse) {
        // my code here handles json string as i need it
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Job Received...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showja();  
     }
 }
```

and then you would use the task like this, instead of your `Thread`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    JsonRequestTask task = new JsonRequestTask();
    task.execute(httppost);
    ...
}
```

You may run the task again by simply creating a `new JsonRequestTask()` and calling its `execute()` method.

A common practice for a simple async task like this is to make it a private *inner class* within the `Activity` class that uses it (if only one `Activity` needs it).  You may need to change the scope of some of your activity's variables so that the inner class may use them (e.g. move local variables to member variables).